# Java 8 Method Reference more than one different constructors

Tags: java, lambda, reference, java-8, functional-interface

I'm trying to write a method that takes a constructor of a Runnable class and runs it in a certain way, according to the constructor that was input.

So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
executeInParallel(someRunnable::new)
executeInParallel(someOtherRunnable::new)
```

My question is how do I define the `executeInParallel` method in order to be able to pass any of the Runnable constructors I've defined in the parameters? Essentially my question is in order to do that what how do I define this method?
    `void executeInParallel(??){ ... }`

It seems that I can only have methods that adhere to a Functional Interface as parameters though, so I can't define `executeInParallel` with a single parameter that accepts more than one `xRunnable::new` constructors  Is there a way for me to do this without using some sort of a Factory pattern?

I want to make clear that the reason I want to do this is that I want to pass in constructors and not instances. I can't generate the instance outside executeInParallel, it has to be generated inside that method. I also want to pass in *different* constructors that take *different* parameters

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**
Sorry, I made the question a little more clear hopefully.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? What are you trying to do?

Comment: When using the reference `CLASS::new`, a 0-arg constructor would fit the `Supplier<CLASS>` FI, a 1-arg constructor with arg of type T would fit the `Function<T,CLASS>` FI, a 2-arg constructor with arg types of T, U would fit `BiFunction<T,U,CLASS>`, and you can define your own functional interfaces if you need any more parameters. Is there a constructor pattern for which you can't create a functional interface to match?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to reduce the various FI types to a Runnable?

Comment: @HankD Yeah I'm trying to have a single interface that accepts any Runnable constructor I throw at it. It seems however that I can only have a functional interface as a parameter to a method, which is kind of strange to me and was wondering if that was actually the case and whether or not I am missing something.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you actually want to pass *constructors* and not *instances*? Why does your method need to create instances itself? Does it create more than one instance before running it? Can you please explain what you want your method to do exactly?

Comment: Please, give us an example that doesn't work with your solution. What is the difference between `someRunnable::new` and `someOtherRunnable::new` that prevents your solution from working?

Comment: @zeroflagL The problem is how am I going to define the parameters for executeInParallel in order for it to be able to accept two different types of constructors for two different runnable classes with potentially different parameters?It seems that  I can only have a functional interface as a parameter in the method that's the problem.

Comment: @Joffrey Yeah I need the method itself to create the instances, because only this method has the appropriate data structures to pass into the constructors in order to create the instances. I can't create the instances at the place where I need to call this method; That's why I need to pass in constructors and not instances. I want to define different algorithms on top of something, and have a single generic method that would execute these algorithms in parallel in a certain way.

Comment: If the constructors have different parameters and maybe even more than one, then how does `executeInParallel` which arguments to pass to the constructor?

Comment: @zeroflagL It decides based on some other variables... Maybe what I'm trying to do doesn't make much sense... I'm just trying to re-use code as much as possible.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn’t make much sense. You can always create overloaded methods taking different parameters which will later-on internally invoke a method containing the actual common stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `executeInParallel()` method accepts something that will generate a Runnable, so its signature should be `executeInParallel(Supplier<? extends Runnable> runnableFactory)`

Then, you can call it with any lambda or method reference that can return an instance of any class that implements `Runnable`.

Possible usages :

```
// Ex 1 :
class MyJob implements Runnable { 
    public void run() {...} 
}
executeInParallel(() -> new MyJob());
executeInParallel(MyJob::new);
```

```
// Ex 2 :
class MyJobWithParams implements Runnable {
    public MyJobWithParams(String param1, int param2) { ... }
    public void run() {...} 
}
executeInParallel( () -> new MyJobWithParams("Hello",42) );
// You cannot use method references here
```

```
// Ex 3 : 
class RunnableFactory {
    public static Runnable makeRunnable() {
        return new MyJob(); // which is a Runnable, see above
    }
}
executeInParallel( () -> RunnableFactory.makeRunnable() );
executeInParallel( RunnableFactory::makeRunnable );
```

Also, you state that you only want Runnable constructors to be passed to the method. This can be done via a method reference (but only for a no-arg constructor), or via a lambda expression (like in example #1 and #2 above).

Comment: Thanks, This is something that came to mind but I don't really like the factory pattern if I don't absolutely have to use it, so I was wondering if there was some other way to do this using interfaces.

Comment: It is not necessarily a factory pattern, don't be confused by the name of the parameter. The `Supplier` interface is actually the right functional interface for a no-arg constructor of a subclass of `Runnable`. @OlivierCroisier gave that name because it is more general than just constructors, it could take *any* method that returns an instance of a subclass of Runnable.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by this answer now... The text says to have the method accept a Supplier which actually generates a runnable class of my choice. How would I pass in the parameter that tells it what to generate? I can't pass in parameters through a method reference, so I don't see how this would work. I'd have to decide which runnable to generate inside `executeInParallel` which is pointless that's not what I want to do.

Comment: I will complete my code snipper above to show you others ways to pass a `Supplier<Runnable>` to the method

Comment: @OlivierCroisier Thanks again